# Universal Apps and PlayerFramework

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm creating a Universal App, starting with the Phone part.

I successfully installed [PlayerFramework](https://playerframework.codeplex.com/releases/view/121773) and added it as a reference.

But when I add the `MediaPlayer` element to my `App.xaml`, I get the following error:

```
The name "MediaPlayer" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.PlayerFramework".
```

My `App.xaml` looks like this:

```
<Application
x:Class="MusicTracker.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyNameSpace!"
xmlns:mmppf="using:Microsoft.PlayerFramework">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style  x:Key="RootFrameStyle" TargetType="Frame">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame">
                    <Grid>
                        <mmppf:MediaPlayer x:Name="MediaPlayer" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AutoPlay="True"  />
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

[image: capture]

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild the project? If you use it in a normal XAML page, it works? I use it and it works fine

Comment: I've tried rebuilding and cleaning and whatnot, doesn't change. Did not yet try it in a normal page, because I want to play media across multiple pages, that's why I use the App.xaml.

Comment: @the_nuts Adding it to a normal page within my WP8.1 project gives the same error. I can't see what I'm doing wrong ..

Comment: Have you installed the "Additional downloads" required? (smooth streaming SDK, PlayReady Client SDK...) Are the samples working? (https://playerframework.codeplex.com/downloads/get/845207 )

Comment: @the_nuts The samples are working, even though my project has the exact same references. I'm going to try a new project tonight and see what's wrong.